# Insert table rows based on concatenated rows from a series

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

Two tables, 'user' and 'tracks' and I want to create a user for each track that doesn't already have one (userid=0).

We don't have the unique emails required for user so aim to create dummy emails using generate_series:

```
insert into users (username, email) 
select artist, (
select concat(generate_series(1, (SELECT COUNT(filename) 
                FROM tracks where userid = 0)),'@domain.com')
                ) as email
from tracks 
where userid = 0 
group by artist;
```

Of course getting the error:

```
'ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'
```

I could use two SQL calls and have the parent code (Python) perform the loop, but I imagine the right way to do it is just within the SQL statement.

So how do I make the Insert statement sort of, 'loop' through the select?

The expected output:

```
 id  |                         username                          |         email         
-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------
  62 | Sam Jackson                                               | 1@infiniteglitch.net
  63 | (unknown person)                                          | 2@infiniteglitch.net
  64 | Howard Cocel J.                                           | 3@infiniteglitch.net
```

Comment: Could you add to the question the expected output from the `SELECT` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` window function:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email)
(SELECT artist, row_number() OVER () || '@domain.com'    
   FROM (SELECT artist
    FROM tracks 
    WHERE userid = 0 
    GROUP BY artist) sq1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question you need the following query. It is not necessary to create a second query because you operate on the same table (tracks) and on the same userid (0).

```
insert into users (username, email) 
select 
artist, 
concat(generate_series(1, COUNT(filename)),'@domain.com') as email
from tracks 
where userid = 0 
group by artist;
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work because `COUNT(filename)` is only getting up to one (or two if there  are two files for that artist). If I substitute a number (like the result of `SELECT COUNT(filename) from tracks;`, which is `24`, it returns `24` emails for each artist.